# Высота страницы html

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Стоит задача реализовать сайт на котором страница будет помещаться в высоту экрана без прокрутки, т.е. выглядеть как приложение, если я задаю высоту экрана своего ноутбука в пикселях, то все хорошо, но как быть с мониторами с большим разрешением?

Comment: Вам подошёл какой либо ответ? Если да, то отметьте его, как принятый. Если нет уточните в комментариях, что вам нужно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вариант 1 (`%`):**

```css
html,body,div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div {background: #ccc;}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Вариант 2 (`vh`):**

```css
div {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #ccc; 
}

html, body {margin: 0;}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  padding: 1em;
  background: antiquewhite;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  outline-offset: -1em;
}
```

Comment: Дело в том что по правой стороне не просто бэкграунд а изображение, и чтобы оно появилось, у блока должна быть высота, если задать ему высоту в пикселсях то при большом разрешении все равно появляется граница и дальше белый экран

Comment: @vovaxxx, в процентах задай.

Answer (score 1):

Просто установите `body` свойство `height: 100vh;`. `vh` — это viewport height, то есть величина относительно окна браузера.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html,body{ 
height:100%;
}

.your-div-class{
height:100%;
}
```

http://codepen.io/DavidKern/pen/avgbRM

Comment: Спасибо, и за ссылку спасибо, есть чему поучиться)